# Simple Screen recorder doesn't record my own voice

Tags: 18.04, sound, screen, sound-recorder

I am using simple screen recorder software for recording audio and screen but it doesn't work as expected. Currently, it doesn't record audio from my microphone. However, it records other person's audio on a video call.  I tried with and without my headsets but the issues persist. I even try to check for alternatives but other software doesn't record another person's audio on a video call. Could someone suggest to me any other software for Ubuntu or if there are any changes do I need to make in SimpleScreenRecorder

Comment: there are two possible recommendations to consider: [first one for 18.04](https://itsfoss.com/record-screen-ubuntu-simplescreenrecorder/) the second is to upgrade to 22.04 [see this from the Ubuntu Handbook](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/record-desktop-with-sound-ubuntu-2204/)

Comment: I have already tried the things mentioned in the link it didn't work for me. And I can't upgrade to 22.04 due to some restriction

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/695905/cannot-record-microphone-with-simplescreenrecorder https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681438/how-to-mix-two-input-sources-in-pulseaudio-for-recording-mic-and-speakers-with

Comment: or you can use OBS, but that's a bit more complicated. (many, many more features, though!)